# Apache + PHP-FPM = random "Error parsing script headers" + Seg Faults

Tags: php, httpd, php-fpm, apache-2.4

I have PHP-FPM setup with Apache 2.4 using proxy_fcgi, all works fine, but every one in 4-6 requests, Apache returns a blank page. This happens on my main site http://danielhe.com/, but not subdomain vhosts.

This shows up Apache's error log,
[client x] AH01070: Error parsing script headers

And eventually, sometimes Apache segfaults
AH00052: child pid 9740 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

I can reproduce the "Error parsing script headers" very easily by refreshing the page a couple times, but the seg fault happens randomly after a couple of "Error parsing script headers"

*Update*
I have found a fix for the seg faults, and the WSOD has apparently fixed itself.
mod_deflate has some issues, but this config from the Apache documentation fixed it

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as an accepted answer to make this question looks like a solved one

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use this configuration

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

Comment: Are you sure that problem is in mod_deflate? Any references? Looks very strange...

Comment: @GioMac: I've no idea - the OP says that's what solved the problem in the question. I just put it in an answer. Note that SO sent it to us and it was originally answered on March 9th 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the above solution worked for me but I had to fix my ProxyPassmatch settings as well.

Old config

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/YOURDOMAIN/public_html/$1
</IfModule>
```

New config - different rewrite filter, plus code from above

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
ProxyPassMatch ^(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/YOURDOMAIN/public_html/$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
...code from above
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the response from phpList doesn’t fill a full package. php-fpm breaks off connection with Apache prematurely if its response doesn’t fill at least one buffer. As a work-around you can switch to mod_php temporarily or pad out the response with some randomly generated text.

Comment: interesting, and sir how would one do that?